# Menu Error displaying info on a List

Tags: c#, menu

Im having problems with a menu I made for a small app I am doing for a school project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Teste_Menu
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Modelo> ListaModelo = new List<Modelo>();
            ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Civic", 180, 29000));
            ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Jazz", 100, 15000));
            ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "HRV", 115, 22500));
        }

        static void Menu()
        {
            string escolha;

            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;

                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Console.WriteLine(" ==================================================================================================== ");
                Console.WriteLine(" =========================================== Cars ================================================= ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ==================================================================================================== \n\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.WriteLine(" Consultar Lista de Carros -----------------------------------------------> (1)\n  ");


                escolha = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (escolha)
                {
                    case "1": ListaModelo();
                        break;
                }
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            while (escolha != "2");
        }

        static void ListaModelo()
        {
             {
                 var ListaModelo = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 50));

                 ListaModelo.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
             }
        }

    }
}
```

When I execute it shows no Erros but doesn't give any output.What am I doing wrong here?
It just shows  - "Press any key to continue"

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args){
    List<Modelo> ListaModelo = new List<Modelo>();
    ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Civic", 180, 29000));
    ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "Jazz", 100, 15000));
    ListaModelo.Add(new Modelo("Honda", "HRV", 115, 22500));
    Menu();
}
```

you didn't call the menu function that's why it didn't gives any output. If still no output, try to pass your list.

Comment: This started the program but it only gives me an output of 0 to 50 and doesn't show the 3 models I have on my list.

Comment: @Dany4k Try to past your list on your method. For naming convention, try to rename your function name so that it won't be confusing to your list name. In your fuction, static void function_name(List<modelo> myList){....}.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Main` method simply creates a list and adds items to it; the rest of your code never runs. The end of `Main` hits and the program exits (as all C# programs do when the end of `Main` is reached) You need to actually *invoke* the `Menu` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   ...
   Menu();
}
```

You might also consider passing in the list of cars, because its not going to be available to any other methods where you have it right now either.

Comment: Thanks, it worked and the menu its initiated but the problem is that it outputs a list of number of 1 to 50, and not the models I listed.

Comment: @Dany4k That is because you call the ListaModelo method which does exactly that. As I mentioned, you need to pass in or otherwise use the list you created. It seems like you need to go back to the drawing board a bit, probably talk with your instructor, as you don't seem to understand methods and variables yet.